# PHP replace "\[" with "<script>"

Tags: php, regex

I have a long text that contains `\[` and I want to replace it with the tag `<script>`. `\[` appears many times in the text.How can I do the replacement at once using PHP?

Comment: str_replace('[','<script>',$text)...this would help

Comment: or preg_replace("[", "<script>", $text)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need regex, try [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

```
$mytext = str_replace('\[','<script>',$mytext);
```

Do be sure though that you really do want all `[` to be replaced by `<script>` (I assume you're also replacing `]` by `</script>` too) - what about nested/unbalanced/escaped ones, etc (it may be that your input is guaranteed to be free of these problem cases, but it's worth considering).

Comment: Yes.I'll be replacing the `\]` with </script>.There will not be any nested ones. Actually the string to be replaced is `\[` - backward slash followed by square bracket.

Answer (score 1):

You would use str_replace.

```
$replaced = str_replace('[', '<script>', $longtext);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$NewString = str_replace("\\[", "<script>", $OldString);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a regex. You can use `str_replace` as:

```
$new = str_replace('[', '<script>', $original);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use

```
str_replace("[", "<script>", $text);
```

for that

Answer (score 0):

Use the PHP Power function `str_replace()`

```
$slashbracketcode = "\[kjsadjkhdkjkjsdk\[kjjkdsjksf\[\[\[jkshdfjkshfkjhs\[";

$clientscript = str_replace('[', '<script>', $slashbracketcode);
```